# Delete Duplicate Rows in SQL Server Express

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, duplicates

I try to delete duplicate rows with the same timestamp in SQL Server Express using Python. I use dataframe and pandas.

This is the code i have so far

```
    sql_conn = pyodbc.connect('''DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};
                                SERVER=LAPTOP-S2U95H31\SQLEXPRESS;
                                DATABASE=Munich-Weather;
                                Trusted_Connection=yes''') 
    cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO dbo.MunichWeather([Timestamp],
                        [Temperature], [Pressure], [Humidity], [City]) 
                         values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", row['dt_txt'], 
                                                row['main.temp'], 
                                                row['main.pressure'],
                                                row['main.humidity'],
                                                row['city']) 
        sql_conn.commit()

    cursor.execute("""
        WITH cte AS (
            SELECT 
                Timestamp,
                Temperature,
                Pressure,
                Humidity,
                City
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY 
                        Timestamp
                    ORDER BY 
                        Timestamp
            ) row_num
         FROM 
            MunichWeather
        )
        DELETE FROM cte
            WHERE row_num > 1""")
    sql_conn.commit()

    cursor.close()
    sql_conn.close()
```

Now, i get an Error saying, wrony syntax close to "(". Python highlights the line:

```
            WHERE row_num > 1;""")
```

I am aware this Code deletes the newer entries, but I want to keep the the newer ones.

Could you help me with this one,
Thanks in Advance
Flaayor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma after City

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT 
            Timestamp,
            Temperature,
            Pressure,
            Humidity,
            City
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY 
                    Timestamp
                ORDER BY 
                    Timestamp
        ) row_num
     FROM 
        MunichWeather
    )
    DELETE FROM cte
        WHERE row_num > 1
```

should be:

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT 
            Timestamp,
            Temperature,
            Pressure,
            Humidity,
            City,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY 
                    Timestamp
                ORDER BY 
                    Timestamp
        ) row_num
     FROM 
        MunichWeather
    )
    DELETE FROM cte
        WHERE row_num > 1
```

Comment: Well, that was a stupid mistake. I tried this before and it didn't work, but i also got the data type wrong and changed it from nchar(10) to nvarchar(MAX) and now everything works! Thanks a lot!